# C# - How to give a default value using LINQ when the value returned is null

Tags: c#, linq, null

So I'm using LINQ to retrieve an accounts email for the first account that has the name John. However, if one can't be found I want to return an empty string.

Here Is my code:

```
string Email = Accounts?.Where(x => x.Name == "John").Select(z => z.Email).First() ?? string.Empty
```

Why does this return null and not the empty string?

Comment: What this actually does, if `Accounts` is not null, but there are no accounts named "John", is crash with an `InvalidOperationException`, "Sequence contains no elements". You probably want `FirstOrDefault()`, not `First()`.

Comment: @gnud thank you this works was not aware of FirstOrDefault()

Comment: That line will never return `null`. I made a test with several variations of the list, and it's never `null`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tzLlM9 You either get an empty string, or an exception.

Comment: Just FYI: you can condense your Linq query to: `Accounts?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "John")?.Email ?? ""`

Comment: @elgonzo nice, but if this is a LINQ provider like Entity Framework, you probably want the `Select` there so you don't fetch the entire Account object.

Comment: @gnud, true...!

Answer (score 0):

You used ternary if. You should write to else condition. For example:

```
string Email = Accounts?.Where(x => x.Name == "John").Select(z => z.Email).First() ?? string.Empty : Accounts?.Where(x => x.Name == "John").Select(z => z.Email).First()
```

Can you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try null coalescing to set it to an empty string if your query returns null:

```
string email = Accounts?.Where(x => x.Name == "John").FirstOrDefault()?.Email ?? string.Empty;
```